# Angular material md-content

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-material

Good evening, I have such a problem, why not "angular material md-content (infinite scroll)" loaded information scroll.

The first information goes well, the rest is not loads.
Help please, really need your help, I have a problem with English (if that is not clear ask)

```
<md-content flex class="Body--Content" id="contentWrapper">
    <div class="container padding-container">
        //content
    </div>
  </md-content>
```

Comment: It is not clear what is the problem. Can you provide more details?

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<div flex layout="row"> <md-content flex></md-content> </div>
```